# Trying to add 2 workday numbers in separate cells to a date minus holidays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Adding days to a date][1]

I need to add 2 workday #s in separate cells to a date in a 3rd cell minus holidays. It always works with 1 # but 2 will not work.

Cell `I75` reads the # `14`

Cell `Q45` reads `105`

Cell `AF72` reads `8/31/2021`

Holidays `B2:B15`

The basic formula: `=workday(AF72,I75,Holidays!$B2:$B15)` works but I need it to also add Cell Q45 and it will not work or I am setting it up incorrectly.

Comment: Have you tried `=workday(AF72,I75+Q45,Holidays!$B2:$B15) `? What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=WORKDAY(AF72,I75+Q45,$B2:$B15)
```

[image]